# AngularJS Direcitve - link function doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

What I'm trying to achieve: 
wrapping cordova native handlers inside an angular directive

I would like to implement handlers for Cordova's native events using a directive wrapper (in order to listen to the body load event).

I have the following directive boilerplate:

```
angular.module('vitaApp')
  .directive('cordovaNative', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function (element, attrs, transcludeFn) {
          alert('compile fired');
         element.bind('load', function(){
              alert('load occured');
          });
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          alert('link fired');
          element.bind('load', function(){
              alert('load occured');
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

Which is instantiated in the following way:

```
<body ng-app="vitaApp"  ng-controller="metaCtrl" ng-swipe-right="showMenu()"  ng-swipe-left="hideMenu()" cordova-native>
```

Compile function for cordovaNative directive fires, but the link function doesn't.

Could it have something to do with the ng-swipe directives (e.g. '{terminal: true}')?

Note: I am not trying to use `compile` and `link` together, I am trying to demonstrate that non of them works for the purpose of subscribing to the `load` event separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have both compile and link function in a directive. If you use compile you should return a function, which itself is a link function. So the above code becomes:

```
 compile: function (elem, attrs, transcludeFn) {
          alert('compile fired');
          return function(scope, element, attrs) {
             alert('link fired');
             element.on('load', function(){
                alert('load occured');
             });
          }
      },
```

**Update**: Since the directive link function runs after an element is loaded (mostly) adding `element load` event handler inside directive link function may not be required.

Comment: I removed the compile function, but the load callback for the body element still doesn't fire.

Comment: Most probably by the time you have subscribed for the event the element is already loaded.

Comment: Moved the event subscription to the compile function, tried to use both `on` and `bind`, still no luck.
Could probably hack this out with a `$timeout` of 0, but not sure if I want to.

Comment: Why do you want to subscribe to load? If the directive is called the element is loaded

Comment: Well, because there is no assurance of that, is there?
And I must assure that the binding for the cordova native handlers occur after the load event.

Comment: A directive only runs once the DOM element is loaded.

Comment: Not true: example: <img> DOM node

Comment: I can accept the answer if you will edit it and include the fact that the load occurs before the link\compile functions are executed

Answer (score 3):

From the Angular Docs:

```
link

This property is used only if the compile property is not defined.
```

Since you have a Compile function defined, the link function is not needed. There is [more information about it here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the link function if the compile function is not defined. So in your case, because the compile function is defined, you have to return the postLink function or an object with the preLink and postLink functions.

```
.directive('cordovaNative', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function (elem, attrs, transcludeFn) {
      return {
          pre: function preLink() {
             alert('Pre link');
          },
          post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
              alert('link fired');
              element.bind('load', function(){
                  alert('load occured');
              });
          }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Or if you don't need a preLink function:

```
.directive('cordovaNative', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function (elem, attrs, transcludeFn) {
      return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                  alert('link fired');
                  element.bind('load', function(){
                      alert('load occured');
                  });
             }
    }
  };
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7330/).

Comment: I removed the compile function, but the load callback for the body element still doesn't fire.

Comment: JQuery won’t listen to body onLoad event, instead you should listen to window’s load. Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gajotemeyote/1/edit)

Comment: The function I attach to the load event is never fired, I suppose the right solution is not to use an event at all 

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7338/

Comment: Agree. On the other hand, if you are working with cordova, maybe you should only start the app once 'deviceready' event fired.